# Coq - undocumented error on induction with eqn:

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Using Coq 8.4pl3, I'm getting an error on induction with the **eqn:** variant that is not listed under induction in the reference manual.

```
(* Export below requires Software Foundations 4.0. *)
Require Export Logic.

Inductive disjoint (X : Type) (l1 l2 : list X) : Prop :=
  | nil1 : l1 = [] -> disjoint X l1 l2
  | nil2 : l2 = [] -> disjoint X l1 l2
  | bothCons : forall x:X, 
                 In x l1 -> 
                   not (In x l2) -> 
                     disjoint X l1 l2.

Fixpoint head (X : Type) (l : list X) : option X :=
  match l with
  | [] => None
  | h :: t => Some h
  end.

Fixpoint tail (X : Type) (l : list X) : list X :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | h :: t => t
  end.

Inductive NoDup (X : Type) (l : list X) : Prop :=
  | ndNil : l = [] -> NoDup X l
  | ndSingle : forall x:X, l = [x] -> NoDup X l
  | ndCons : forall x:X, head X l = Some x ->
               not (In x (tail X l)) /\ NoDup X (tail X l) -> 
                 NoDup X l.

Theorem disjoint__app_NoDup : 
      forall (X : Type) (l1 l2 : list X),
        disjoint X l1 l2 /\ NoDup X l1 /\ NoDup X l2 ->
          NoDup X (l1 ++ l2).
Proof.
      intros. induction H eqn:caseEqn.
```

If I substitute just plain "induction H" for the last step, I get no error, but with the above eqn: argument, I get the error:

> Error: a is used in conclusion.

(Previously there was a condition missing in the theorem statement, and the same error listed an identifier **d** instead.)

Ref manual lists "is used in conclusion" as an error from use of **assert**.  It makes some kind of sense that behind the scenes, **eqn:** might be generating assertions, but I have no identifier **a** visible in the context, and I can't see what Coq is trying to automatically do with it.

Tried replacing beginning of the proof with

```
  intros. remember H. induction H.
```

Now the attempt to do induction gives the same error as before, only with **H** instead of **a**.  (When the theorem was missing the additional condition, Coq also explicitly added a **d** to the context, identical to the hypothesis **H**.)

How can I move forward here?  I'm trying to avoid losing information from the context.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with all imports would be very helpful. E.g. there is no `disjoint` (all lower-case) in the standard library.

Comment: For what it's worth, your theorem is probably not right.  The lists `[1;1`] and `[2;2]` are disjoint, but `[1;1]++[2;2]` contains duplicates. Perhaps you should also require that `NoDup l1 /\ NoDup l2`.

Comment: (1) The problem here is the definition of `disjoint` - it's not actually inductive, since its constructors don't include any `disjoint` as premises, only as conclusions. So `induction H eqn:caseEqn.` can be replaced with `destruct H eqn:caseEqn.` (2) Also, the `bothCons` constructor is actually a definition for the whole `disjoint` concept, we can derive `nil1` and `nil2` from it, so you could define `disjoint` this way: `Definition disjoint {X : Type} (l1 l2 : list X) : Prop := forall x:X, In x l1 -> ~ (In x l2).`

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you to take a look at the definition of `NoDup` in the [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html).

Comment: Anton, thanks for the education.  Perhaps I'm very naive here, but I thought if the Coq type checker accepted an inductive definition, it must be well-formed?

Comment: **(1)** Indeed, it's well-formed and you *can* prove your theorem using it, but the first 2 constructors are redundant -- they are not independent of the 3d one, and such independence is a thing your usually strive for, moreover, it doesn't generate a useful induction principle. If you'd try my definition (or something similar), then you could use induction on a list.

Comment: **(2)** Another approach would be something like this: `Inductive disjoint_i {X : Type} : list X -> list X -> Prop := dnil : forall l2, disjoint_i [] l2 | dcons : forall l1 l2 x, ~ (In x l2) -> disjoint_i l1 l2 -> disjoint_i (x::l1) l2.` It's a truly inductive definition with independent cases and one can prove it is equivalent to the non-inductive one I gave earlier. It may not be very convenient to use in all circumstances since it lacks symmetry, but I believe it can be straighten out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor bug; I've [reported it](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6863).  However, the thing you are trying to do here is not particularly sensible.  Note that you are invoking `induction` on a conjunction (`/\`), and asking Coq to leave you an equation that says that the original hypothesis is equal to the conjunction of the two generated proofs.  There are two issues here:

1. Your hypothesis is not used in a dependent fashion anywhere, so you don't need to remember it.
2. Your hypothesis is not recursive, so you could just as well do `destruct H` rather than `induction H`.

As for the error message, it becomes a bit more clear if you note that replacing `/\` with `*` makes `induction H eqn:caseEqn` go through, and breaks your hypothesis apart into two parts named `a` and `b`.  The actual issue is that the proof term constructed by `induction H eqn:...` is ill-typed when `H`'s type is a `Prop`, because you cannot eliminate `Prop`s to get information.  I suspect that the code simply tries to do something with the `a` that it creates in a particular way, and assumes that any failure to do that must be because `a` is used in the conclusion, rather than because the proof term it was creating was ill-formed.